# Service fabric remoting serializer

Tags: serialization, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateful

In experimenting with Service Fabric remoting I have some data types that are not serialized correctly. This is causing me many issues.

From the documentation it appears that everything needs to be decorated with [DataContract]. After using this on some test types it does appear that they serialize correctly.

However I frankly don't want to have to decorate everything. That would be a huge step backwards for me. I would prefer to use custom serialization all the way around.

This [documentation](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/78e595701b4117371074db450eb0c5692914d804/articles/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-serialization.md) seems to suggest that it is possible to register a custom serializer however it appears to only be for stateful services. I am primarily using remoting with stateless services.

Comment: `From the documentation it appears that everything needs to be decorated with [DataContract].` you don't have to

Comment: That is true. [DataContract] will try to serialize what it can. However anything that can't be serialized needs explicit help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current remoting stack requires that your types use DataContract. Supposedly the team is close to releasing a new remoting stack in the near future that contains the ability to plug in custom serialization and a lot of improvements on the performance side but this is not available yet.

In the meantime, a workaround (not a very nice one mind you) is to make all of your proxies receive `string` or `byte[]` or something like that and take care of serialization/deserialization manually using something like JSON.Net. Personally I'd bite the bullet and make your types Data Contract Serializable until the new remoting bits are available.

Comment: Thanks for the information. This currently sounds like the best approach.

Answer (score 2):

With the release of Service Fabric V2 Remoting, this is now possible. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-remoting#how-to-use-custom-serialization-with-remoting-v2.) for further details. Below

Here is an implementation of [MessagePack](https://msgpack.org/index.html) remoting serializer I have used, but in your case the JSON example in the docs would probably suffice.

```
    public class MessagePackMessageFactory : IServiceRemotingMessageBodyFactory
    {
        public IServiceRemotingRequestMessageBody CreateRequest(string interfaceName, string methodName, int numberOfParameters)
        {
            return new MessagePackRemotingRequestMessageBody(numberOfParameters);
        }

        public IServiceRemotingResponseMessageBody CreateResponse(string interfaceName, string methodName)
        {
            return new MessagePackServiceRemotingResponseMessageBody();
        }
    }


 [MessagePackObject]
  public class MessagePackRemotingRequestMessageBody : IServiceRemotingRequestMessageBody
  {
    [Key(0)]
    public object Value;

    public MessagePackRemotingRequestMessageBody()
    {
    }

    public MessagePackRemotingRequestMessageBody(int parameterInfos)
    {

    }

    public void SetParameter(int position, string paramName, object parameter)
    {
      Value = parameter;
    }

    public object GetParameter(int position, string paramName, Type paramType)
    {
      return Value;
    }
  }

 [MessagePackObject]
  public class MessagePackServiceRemotingResponseMessageBody : IServiceRemotingResponseMessageBody
  {
    [Key(0)]
    public object Response;

    public object Get(Type paramType)
    {
      // ignore paramType?
      return Response;
    }

    public void Set(object response)
    {
      Response = response;
    }
  }

 public class ServiceRemotingResponseMessagePackMessageBodySerializer : IServiceRemotingResponseMessageBodySerializer
    {
        public OutgoingMessageBody Serialize(IServiceRemotingResponseMessageBody responseMessageBody)
        {
            if (!(responseMessageBody is MessagePackServiceRemotingResponseMessageBody body))
            {
                return new OutgoingMessageBody(new[] { new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[0]) });
            }

            var bytes = MessagePackSerializer.Serialize(body, ServiceFabricResolver.Instance);

            return new OutgoingMessageBody(new[] { new ArraySegment<byte>(bytes) });
        }

        public IServiceRemotingResponseMessageBody Deserialize(IncomingMessageBody messageBody)
        {
            using (var stream = messageBody.GetReceivedBuffer())
            {
                if (stream.Length == 0)
                {
                    return new MessagePackServiceRemotingResponseMessageBody();
                }

                var body = MessagePackSerializer.Deserialize<MessagePackServiceRemotingResponseMessageBody>(stream, ServiceFabricResolver.Instance);
                return body;
            }
        }
    }

 public class ServiceRemotingMessagePackSerializationProvider : IServiceRemotingMessageSerializationProvider
  {
    public IServiceRemotingRequestMessageBodySerializer CreateRequestMessageSerializer(Type serviceInterfaceType,
      IEnumerable<Type> requestBodyTypes)
    {
      return new ServiceRemotingRequestMessagePackMessageBodySerializer();
    }

    public IServiceRemotingResponseMessageBodySerializer CreateResponseMessageSerializer(Type serviceInterfaceType, IEnumerable<Type> responseBodyTypes)
    {
      return new ServiceRemotingResponseMessagePackMessageBodySerializer();
    }

    public IServiceRemotingMessageBodyFactory CreateMessageBodyFactory()
    {
      return new MessagePackMessageFactory();
    }
  }

 public class ServiceRemotingRequestMessagePackMessageBodySerializer : IServiceRemotingRequestMessageBodySerializer
    {
        public OutgoingMessageBody Serialize(IServiceRemotingRequestMessageBody serviceRemotingRequestMessageBody)
        {
            if (serviceRemotingRequestMessageBody == null) return null;

            if (!(serviceRemotingRequestMessageBody is MessagePackRemotingRequestMessageBody body))
            {
                return new OutgoingMessageBody(new[] { new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[0]) });
            }

            var bytes = MessagePackSerializer.Serialize(body, ServiceFabricResolver.Instance);

            return new OutgoingMessageBody(new[] { new ArraySegment<byte>(bytes) });
        }

        public IServiceRemotingRequestMessageBody Deserialize(IncomingMessageBody messageBody)
        {
            using (var stream = messageBody.GetReceivedBuffer())
            {
                if (stream.Length == 0)
                {
                    return new MessagePackRemotingRequestMessageBody();
                }

                var body = MessagePackSerializer.Deserialize<MessagePackRemotingRequestMessageBody>(stream, ServiceFabricResolver.Instance);
                return body;
            }
        }
    }
```